# Create multi-part message in MIME format Freemarker template via Spring 3 JavaMail

Tags: html, spring, email, text, mime

How do you create email message that contains text and HTML version for the same content?

Of course I would like to know how to setup the freemarker template or the header of the message that will be send.

When I look on the source of message multi-part message in MIME format that I receive in inbox every once in while this is what is in there:

```
This is a multi-part message in MIME format.

------=_NextPart_000_B10D_01CBAAA8.F29DB300
Content-Type: text/plain
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

...Text here...

------=_NextPart_000_B10D_01CBAAA8.F29DB300
Content-Type: text/html;
charset="iso-8859-1"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

<html><body> html code here ... </body></html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you spot any inconsistencies please let me know. I had to extract this from pretty complex object so that's why this looks like it does.

```
//some important imports
import freemarker.template.Template;
import org.springframework.mail.javamail.*;
import org.springframework.context.*;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.freemarker.FreeMarkerConfigurer;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;

private JavaMailSender mailSender;
private MessageSource messageSource;
private ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(50);

MimeMessagePreparator preparator = new MimeMessagePreparator() {
    public void prepare(MimeMessage mimeMessage) throws Exception {
        MimeMessageHelper message = new MimeMessageHelper(mimeMessage);

            message.setFrom(from);
            message.setTo(recipient);
            message.setSubject(subject);

            // Now the message body.
            Multipart mp = new MimeMultipart();

            BodyPart textPart = new MimeBodyPart();
            Template textTemplate = freemarkerConfig.getConfiguration().getTemplate(textEmailTemplate); // "/WEB-INF/emailText/*.ftl"
            final StringWriter textWriter = new StringWriter();
            textEmailTemplate.process(modelMap, textWriter);
            textPart.setText(textWriter.toString()); // sets type to "text/plain"


            BodyPart pixPart = new MimeBodyPart();
            Template pixTemplate = freemarkerConfig.getConfiguration().getTemplate(pixEmailTemplate); // "/WEB-INF/emailPix/*.ftl"
            final StringWriter pixWriter = new StringWriter();
            textEmailTemplate.process(modelMap, pixWriter);
            pixPart.setContent(pixWriter.toString(), "text/html");

            // Collect the Parts into the MultiPart
            mp.addBodyPart(textPart);
            mp.addBodyPart(pixPart);
            // Put the MultiPart into the Message
             message.setContent(mp);                  

     }
};

executor.submit(new SendMail(preparator));

class SendMail extends Thread {
    MimeMessagePreparator preparator;

    SendMail(MimeMessagePreparator preparator) {
        this.preparator = preparator;
    }

    public void run() {
        mailSender.send(preparator);
      }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

When using Spring you can do:

```
  String plainText = "MyPleinText";
  String htmlText = "<html><body><h1>MyHTML</h1></body></html>";
  MimeMessage message = this.mailSender.createMimeMessage();
  MimeMessageHelper helper = new MimeMessageHelper(message, true, MAIL_ENCODING);
  helper.setText(plainText,htmlText);
```

And it will do the job.
There is no Freemarker stuff involved.

The MailSender can be:

```
  <bean id="mailSender" class="org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl">
    <property name="host" value="${smtp.host}" />
    <property name="port" value="${smtp.port}" />
    <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
  </bean>
```