# How to execute a Struts 2 Action from inside a Quartz job. How to obtain the Container?

Tags: java, struts2, quartz-scheduler

I am trying to execute a Struts2 Action from inside a Quartz job -- generalizing, from any context which is not the processing of an HTTP request.

I started here http://struts.apache.org/2.0.6/docs/how-can-we-schedule-quartz-jobs.html but the document seems to be pretty obsolete.

I believe (but I may be wrong) I've boiled it down to the need to obtain a Container object:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionProxy;
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionProxyFactory;

...

HashMap ctx = new HashMap();
DefaultActionProxyFactory factory= new DefaultActionProxyFactory();
factory.setContainer(HOW DO I GET THE CONTAINER??);
ActionProxy proxy = factory.createActionProxy("", "scheduled/myjob", ctx);
```

One solution would be to issue an http request (via TCP) against localhost. I would prefer to avoid that.

Comment: Why would you want to do this? S2 is specifically a web layer; functionality callable by arbitrary processes should be isolated in services. What S2 functionality do you need to duplicate? Injection? Use Spring. Interceptors?

Comment: I need to render an FreeMarker template to produce the HTML for an e-mail. I can do that -- using some code I inherited and I only half-understand -- from within an Action, but it doesn't work elsewhere.

Comment: lately i am working a lot on Quartz and i do not see any relation between your requirement and S2.Quartz is mainly used to trigger mainly some sort of Job and they are independent of what container you are using as what is more relevant to Quartz will be your service layer.on a curious note why you want to execute your Action from there??

Comment: The e-mail mentioned in my previous answer needs to be sent based on the result of a timed job.

So I need to do something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3985373/getting-template-text-from-freemarker-in-struts2-app -- except that triggered by Quartz and not by an HTTP request.

Comment: @jsalvata:Sending email has nothing to do with S2.

Comment: The code for rendering the template shouldn't be in an action anyway: separate your concerns correctly and eliminate this requirement, it's the wrong way to do it, and a good example of a bad idea. My question still stands--what specific S2 functionality do you believe you need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I somewhat fear what providing this answer may encourage some people to do, but as a proof of concept and to actually provide a solution to anyone who may, for whatever reason (maybe they are inheriting some whacked out application for which this is needed?), need to execute Struts2 actions outside of a normal request context.

But, here is a raw (it is provided as a starting point, not an optimal implementation), but working, solution:

First, add these three classes to a package called com.stackoverflow.struts2.quartz:

A simple job that just asks for a proxy for the given job context and executes it:

```
package com.stackoverflow.struts2.quartz;

import org.quartz.Job;
import org.quartz.JobExecutionContext;
import org.quartz.JobExecutionException;

public class ActionJob implements Job {

    @Override
    public void execute(JobExecutionContext context) throws JobExecutionException {

        try {
            QuartzActionProxyFactory.getActionProxy(context).execute();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new JobExecutionException(e);
        }

    }

}
```

Some constants for passing around the action details:

```
package com.stackoverflow.struts2.quartz;

public class QuartzActionConstants {

    public static final String NAMESPACE = "struts.action.namespace";
    public static final String NAME = "struts.action.name";
    public static final String METHOD = "struts.action.method";

}
```

A custom ActionProxyFactory that can be accessed statically from the ActionJob:

```
package com.stackoverflow.struts2.quartz;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxyFactory;
import org.quartz.JobExecutionContext;
import org.quartz.JobExecutionException;

import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionContext;
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionProxy;
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionProxyFactory;

public class QuartzActionProxyFactory extends StrutsActionProxyFactory {

    private static ActionProxyFactory actionProxyFactory;

    public QuartzActionProxyFactory() {
        actionProxyFactory = this;
    }

    public static ActionProxy getActionProxy(JobExecutionContext context) throws JobExecutionException {

        ActionProxy actionProxy = null;

        try {
            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            Map<String, Object> actionParams = context.getJobDetail().getJobDataMap();
            Map<String, Object> actionContext = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            actionContext.put(ActionContext.PARAMETERS, actionParams);

            actionProxy = actionProxyFactory.createActionProxy(
                    (String) actionParams.get(QuartzActionConstants.NAMESPACE),
                    (String) actionParams.get(QuartzActionConstants.NAME), 
                    (String) actionParams.get(QuartzActionConstants.METHOD), 
                    actionContext, 
                    false, //set to false to prevent execution of result, set to true if this is desired 
                    false);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new JobExecutionException(e);
        }

        return actionProxy;
    }

}
```

Then, in your struts.xml, add:

```
<bean name="quartz" type="com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionProxyFactory" class="com.stackoverflow.struts2.quartz.QuartzActionProxyFactory"/>
<constant name="struts.actionProxyFactory" value="quartz"/>
```

Then you can schedule action executions with some simple code:

```
SchedulerFactory sf = new StdSchedulerFactory();
Scheduler scheduler = sf.getScheduler();
scheduler.start();
JobDetail jobDetail = new JobDetail("someActionJob", Scheduler.DEFAULT_GROUP, ActionJob.class);

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
Map<String, Object> jobContext = jobDetail.getJobDataMap();
jobContext.put(QuartzActionConstants.NAMESPACE, "/the/action/namespace");
jobContext.put(QuartzActionConstants.NAME, "theActionName");
jobContext.put(QuartzActionConstants.METHOD, "theActionMethod");

Trigger trigger = new SimpleTrigger("actionJobTrigger", Scheduler.DEFAULT_GROUP, new Date(), null, SimpleTrigger.REPEAT_INDEFINITELY, 1000L);
scheduler.deleteJob("someActionJob", Scheduler.DEFAULT_GROUP);
scheduler.scheduleJob(jobDetail, trigger);
```

And that's it.  This code will cause the action to be executed every second indefinitely, and the interceptors will all fire and the dependencies will be injected.  Of course, any logic or interceptors that depend on Servlet object like an HttpServletRequest are not going to operate properly, but then it wouldn't make sense to schedule those actions outside of the servlet context, anyway.

Comment: Thanks. It's taken me a while to unravel this, but it's working now.

Essentially it boils down to creating a class (QuartzActionProxyFactory) and configure struts to instantiate it as its Proxy Factory. Then grab the instance statically as soon as it's created (see QuartzActionProxyFactory's constructor) so it can be used elsewhere.

Expect some trouble setting up the proper stacks, etc. so these request-less, session-less actions will work.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need HttpServletRequest to format email in freemarker. See the following answer.

[Create multi-part message in MIME format Freemarker template via Spring 3 JavaMail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4581541/create-multi-part-message-in-mime-format-freemarker-template-via-spring-3-javama)

For sending mail , you can inject the mail component to your Quartz job using spring. Even there is a RequestContextHolder class to retrieve the HttpServlet request, you won't get HttpServletRequest from Quartz job.